# I need help to use composition in Python

Tags: python, composition

I hope you can help me out because I've been wrestling with this for two days now.

I want to make a program in Python to calculate all the nutrition requirement to build mussel.

I've got a dictionary where I stored the number of calories in 1 gr of protein, carbohydrates and Fat, I also have a dictionary containing the different requirements for the nutrition plan  based on the gender

I would like to apply composition in my program, the final result I aim for is a composition class holding:

1. the current day
2. the information of the person
3. and the nutrition plan

I started off by creating a static class for the current day, then a class to print the personal information and finally the class to calculate the nutrition plan based on the information provided in the Personal class

Everything works just fine, I've got the result I wanted to, although when it comes to build my composition class I can't manage to do it, I will put the code I have and I hope you guys can help me with this.

Thank you very much.

```
import datetime
import pytz
calories = {'protein': 4, 'carbohydrates': 4, 'Fat': 9}

building = {
    'man': {'Calories': 44, 'Protein': 2.2, 'carbohydrates': 5,
            'Fat': 0},
    'woman': {'Calories': 44, 'Protein': 2, 'carbohydrates': 5,
              'Fat': 0}
}


class DateInfo:
    @staticmethod
    def current_time():
        utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        print(pytz.utc.localize(utc_time).strftime(
            "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S"))


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, sex, goal):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.sex = sex
        self.goal = goal

    def personal_info(self):
        print('Name:{0.name}\nAge:{0.age}\nWeight:{0.weight}\nGoal:{0.goal}'.format(self))


class Building(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, sex, goal):
        super().__init__(name, age, weight, sex, goal)

    def nutrition_details(self):
        factor = None
        if self.sex == 'Man':
            factor = building['man']
        elif self.sex == 'Woman':
            factor = building['woman']

        total_calories = self.weight * factor['Calories']
        gr_protein = self.weight * factor['Protein']
        gr_carbohydrates = self.weight * factor['carbohydrates']
        gr_fat = (total_calories - (gr_protein * calories['protein']
                                    + gr_carbohydrates * calories['carbohydrates'])) // calories['Fat']

        print(f'Total calories: {total_calories}\n gr of protein'
              f':{gr_protein}\n gr of carbohydrates:'
              f'{gr_carbohydrates}\n gr of fat: {gr_fat}')


# Composition class where I want to store all the data
class NutritionPlan:
    def __init__(self):
        date_time = DateInfo()
        self.person_info = Person()
        self.nutrition_plan = Building()

    def print_nutrition_details(self):
        print(f'Date: {date_time}\nPerson Information: '
              f'{self.person_info}\nNutrition Plan: '
              f'{self.nutrition_plan}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    person_1 = Building('Guillermo', 30, 82, 'Man', 'Building')
    DateInfo().current_time()
    person_1.personal_info()
    person_1.nutrition_details()




**Using composition**
02/02/2023-03:52:31
Name:Guillermo
Age:30
Weight:82
Goal:Building
Total calories: 3608
gr of protein:180.4
gr of carbohydrates:410
gr of fat: 138.0
```

Comment: "I started off by creating a static class for the current day" so, that is not a "static class", there is no such concept in Python. That is just a regular class with a single, static method. This should just be a module-level function. The class does nothing useful, and should just be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you split up `Person` and `Building` into a base-class/sub-class. In any case, if you do this, your current `Building.__init__` does nothing useful. Just remove it, it is pointless.

Comment: Any way, it isn't clear to me what your problem is exactly. What are you trying to accomplish with your `NutritionPlan` class? What problems are you running into exactly.

Comment: I am trying to display the current date, the personal data of person and the nutrition plan using composition. although it does not just work. I tried to do it by using the class NutritionPlan but I am not sure how to build this class using composition

Comment: I split up Person and Building because I'm going to add different kinds of nutrition plans for example for losing weight in the future